# How to add Hyperlink to RichToolTip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use wx.adv.RichToolTps widgets in my GUI to show additional Info to complex Inputs  or if a small Help Info is available etc. At some point i would like to add links to them, mainly to Webpages.

But i cant find a way to add clickable Links to my ToolTips. Is there a way? If no, are there any other Widgets, except for dialogs, i could use for that ?

Here is a small example of how i would like to use them:

```
   def OnHelp(self,event, widget): 
        if widget== self.Img_test:
            self.tip = wx.adv.RichToolTip("Useful Links", "Sea Distances:\nwww.sea-distances.org")
            self.tip.ShowFor(widget)
```

Comment: wxWidgets provides a control for links to an URL [HyperlinkCtrl](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.adv.HyperlinkCtrl.html). But it cannot be used inside a [Rich]ToolTip.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with the Python implementation of wxWidgets, but you could potentially use a `wxPopupTransientWindow`, style it like a `wxRichToolTip` and position it underneath your widget when your event gets fired...

`wxPopupTransientWindow` is a `wxWindow` so you can add a `wxHyperlinkCtrl` to it and handle the event if a user clicks on it. Hope this helps.

As alluded to by @Ripi2, `wxRichToolTip` is not a window and cannot have controls added to it.

Relevant links: 
 - [wx.PopupTransientWindow](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.PopupTransientWindow.html?highlight=popup#phoenix-title-wx-popuptransientwindow) 
 - [C++ Popup Sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/tree/master/samples/popup)